# How to find the IF-ELSE block from my project through reflection?

Tags: c#

This is my code for FXCop Custom Rule. I want to check wheather the method is invoking or not within conditional expression.

```
    public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
    {
         Method method = member as Method;

        if (method != null)
        {
            Block block = method.Body;
            foreach (Statement statement in block.Statements)
            {
                bool IsCondition = false;
                Branch branchingStatement = statement as Branch;

                if (branchingStatement != null)
                {
                    IsCondition = (branchingStatement.Condition != null) && (branchingStatement.Target is Block);
                }
                // Continue traversal only if we detect a loop
                if (IsCondition)
                {
                    Visit(block);
                }
            }
        }
```

but branchingStatement for every method is going null.

Comment: Plz help me in this

Comment: Why don't you just debug it?

Comment: After debugging only Iknew that nothing is coming in the variable branchingStatement.

Comment: No one is there to give the answer ?